# ASP.Net DropDownList in GridView - Codebehind always sees 1st item as selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I am working on an ASP.Net application with code behind as C#. In an aspx page, there is a gridview control. One column contains dropdownlist, as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvModulesSem1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Grade" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gvModulesTextPadding">
            <ItemStyle Width="120px" CSSClass="gvModulesTextPadding" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSelectGrade" Text='<%# Eval("Grade")%>' runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1.0">Select Grade</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Distinction">Distinction</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="A">A</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="B+">B+</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="B">B</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="C+">C+</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="C">C</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="D+">D+</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="D">D</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="P">P</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="F">F</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

There are some other columns too, all of which contain labels. But, to keep it simple, I have removed the codes for the other columns.

In page load, when Page.IsPostBack is false, the GridView is bound to a DataTable (which has been filled). This populates the GridView. All the DropDownLists have the first item i.e. "Select Grade" selected.

As a user, I change the selected items of the dropdown lists. Then click a button (outside the grid). In the button click event procedure, when I try to read the selected item of any dropdown list, I find that it is always the first item.

How do I correct this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: How you take selected item from dropdown list? Can you add js code here?

Comment: I have written C# code. From the GridViewRow object, I do FindControl for "ddlSelectGrade". I typecast the return value to (DropDownList). Then I get SelectedValue of the DropDownList object.